# mysql date formatting with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a date ("mm/dd/yyyy") and I want to convert it to a MySQL DATE data type (like yyyy-mm-dd)

How do I do it with PHP?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at mysql function str_to_date()

example

```
select str_to_date('10/30/2010','%m/%d/%Y') -- 2010-10-30
```

Comment: I nead something like a regex

Answer (score 5):

Nick rulez's answer also applies to inserts and updates:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, date) values (1, str_to_date('10/30/2010','%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do it. 
I like always converting my dates to a timestamp cause I find it easiest to then do what I want.

In which case:

```
<?php
echo date( "Y-m-d",strtotime("09/02/1988"));
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z9vDv7

Comment: What about `03/04/2011`? Is that April 3rd or March 4th? strtotime is handy but it's NOT a magic bullet. Safer to use `date_create_from_format()` when you know what the format is in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your date is in `$your_date`, then:

```
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($your_date));
```

See [strtotime() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: To MySQL, it's still only a string that you *hope* is interpreted as a DATE data type.

Comment: @OMG_Ponies How do you think MySQL processes `DATE` type? This is actually more a string than real time format (like `TIMESTAMP` where the value is stored in a Unix epoch).

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '12/25/2011';
$parts = explode('/', $date);
$sql_date = $parts[2] . '-' . $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[1];
```

Comment: What about '01/02/2011' - is that Feb 1st, or Jan 2nd?  Not everyone's date format is the same...

Comment: My point was, regardless of what the OP says, this solution is not ideal for most situations.

Comment: Of course not. If you have a date `01/02/2011` and you have no idea what each field represents, then there's nothing that can help.

Comment: @OMG it must be the same as it is grabbed from facebook's connect api using the PHP SDK 3, it's the birthday of the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
function date2mysql($date) {

   list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $date);
   $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
   return date("Y-mm-d",$timestamp);
}
```

see the [date manual](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the format