# Generate MySQL Compatible datetime value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am working on a webapp and I need to take a date from input, which will be in the format 2015-02-27 (YYYY-MM-DD) thanks to client side code. It needs to convert this to a MySQL datetime value with the time set as 16:59:00 (eg 2015-02-27 16:59:00).

so far all I have is:

```
function getDateTime($phpDate){
    //please help with thisbit :-)
}
```

This is something I've never even contemplated before but is necessary as my code needs to interact with a third party database which requires this value.
Thanks for any advice...

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql date formatting with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159031/mysql-date-formatting-with-php)

Comment: [Other possible duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+date+php) or [for time, these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+date+time+php).

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your `$phpDate` is a php date type:

```
function getDateTime($phpDate){
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpDate);
}
```