# change PHP POST variable into date format for msql database

Tags: php, mysql

In my code I am using the POST method to store users inputted information into my database. Everything inputs correctly, however I do not understand how I can go about adding a date that a user has inputted, and make the variable recognisable to the date type in the table, the code I have been trying so far:

```
$dateRequired = date("Y-m-d", $dateRequired);



$query = "INSERT INTO CustomerRequest (requestDate, dateRequired, collectionDetails, quantity, requestStatus, customerID) VALUES( NOW(),?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$statement = $cxn->prepare($query);

//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
$statement->bind_param('ssisi', $dateRequired, $details, $quantity, $requestStatus, $customerID);
```

The `$dateRequired` is the variable I am on about, at the moment I get the output of 1970-01-01, and the user inputted value is 04/29/2015. I am obviously doing something wrong but can't figure out which part is the issue, and best way to solve it.

Any ideas on how to get the user entered value for `$dateReqired` recognizable to the mysql database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql date formatting with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159031/mysql-date-formatting-with-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `strtotime()` to convert the data to `timestamp`. `date()` needs the second parameter be a `timestamp` value. Try with -

```
$dateRequired = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateRequired));
```

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Comment: Just a thought, strtotime isn't always reliable depending on your input. Would suggest looking at DateTime::createFromFormat and the DateTime format method.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes. sometimes depending on the format passed.

Comment: @sgtBOSE Well, it is and it isn't. Given the information provided, it isn't strictly, but all that needs to happen is that somebody submits a - separator instead of a / and your dates are wrong or, somebody puts their numbers in the wrong way. It is user input, and strtotime isn't a valid filter. Just pointing out, not saying the answer is wrong ;).

Comment: @JonStirling your point is right. For that some validation are needed.